# Android management API(java) - how to set OpenNetworkConfiguration

Tags: android-management-api

I have a policy manager server implemented in java using this library

```
com.google.apis:google-api-services-androidmanagement:v1-rev20211122-1.32.1
```

The documentation refers that I can set an openNetworkConfiguration inside my policy, and there's a function that supports it.

```
 Policy().setOpenNetworkConfiguration(Map<String, Object>)
```

I have no idea how to fill in data to the parameter Map<String, Object>, and failed to find any clue on searching google and the sample pages. (https://developers.google.com/android/management/sample-app)

How can I put data like this inside the above parameter? Is there a better sample than the link above?

```
"openNetworkConfiguration": {
  "NetworkConfigurations": [{
    "GUID": "a",
    "Name": "Example A",
    "Type": "WiFi",
    "WiFi": {
      "SSID": "Example A",
      "Security": "None",
      "AutoConnect": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fill in the data for the `Map<String, Object>` parameter in the `setOpenNetworkConfiguration` method, you can manually create a nested structure using Java's `HashMap`

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

// ...

Map<String, Object> openNetworkConfig = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> networkConfiguration = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> wifiConfig = new HashMap<>();

wifiConfig.put("SSID", "Example A");
wifiConfig.put("Security", "None");
wifiConfig.put("AutoConnect", true);

networkConfiguration.put("GUID", "a");
networkConfiguration.put("Name", "Example A");
networkConfiguration.put("Type", "WiFi");
networkConfiguration.put("WiFi", wifiConfig);

openNetworkConfig.put("NetworkConfigurations", new Object[]{networkConfiguration});

Policy policy = new Policy();
policy.setOpenNetworkConfiguration(openNetworkConfig);
```

Or you can use the **Gson** library to convert the JSON string to a `Map<String, Object>`

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;


// ...

String json = "{'openNetworkConfiguration': {'NetworkConfigurations': [{'GUID': 'a', 'Name': 'Example A', 'Type': 'WiFi', 'WiFi': {'SSID': 'Example A', 'Security': 'None', 'AutoConnect': true}}]}}";

Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, Object> openNetworkConfig = gson.fromJson(json, type);

Policy policy = new Policy();
policy.setOpenNetworkConfiguration(openNetworkConfig);
```

Comment: It works, but it seems I need a restart after applying the policy, which isn't a big deal for me.